# Dúvida com relacionamento One to Many

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho duas tabelas, `produtos` e `categorias`.
Na minha `view` de `produtos` eu quero mostrar o nome da categoria daquele produto, e não o seu código.

Model de Categoria **Categoria.php**

```php
namespace MagicCommerce\Site\Cadastros;

class Categoria extends \Eloquent {
    public function produtos() {
        return $this->hasMany('Produto');
    }
}
```

Model de Produto **Produto.php**

```php
namespace MagicCommerce\Site\Cadastros;

class Produto extends \Eloquent {
    public function categoria() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Categoria');
    } 
}
```

E na minha `view` eu tento chamar o relacionamento usando:

```php
@foreach ($produtos as $p)
{{ $p->categoria->nome }}
@endforeach
```

E me é retornado o seguinte:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Class
>   'Categoria' not found

Acesso os dados da base normalmente, apenas o relacionamento não funciona.  Também já rodei o `dump-autoload`, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema está na resolução do nome das classes, adicione ao seu `controller`:

```php
use MagicCommerce\Site\Cadastros\Categoria;

use MagicCommerce\Site\Cadastros\Produto;
```

Comment: Na verdade, tem q adicionar isso no seu controller.

Comment: Exato Elena, pois as models estão no mesmo namespace, então não é preciso colocar um use nelas.

Comment: bem lembrado! resposta editada